# Rational homology spheres and geometric properties of the Wu manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I am interested in **simply connected rational homology spheres.** The first such example is in dimension 5 and it is the **Wu manifold** $SU(3)/SO(3)$. You can find a discussion about simply connected rational spheres in: 
[Simply-connected rational homology spheres](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214727/simply-connected-rational-homology-spheres).

I need to understand the geometric properties of this manifold in order to construct mappings with certain properties. So my questions are:

**1. Why is the Wu manifold important except for being a simply connected rational homology sphere?**

**2. Where can I read about the geometric properties of the Wu manifold?**

I am interested more in geometric properties of $SU(3)/SO(3)$ rather than its applications to algebraic topology since, it seems, I have to construct certain mappings explicitly without using algebraic topology. I will describe my problem later in another post.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but for me the Wu manifold is important because it generates the group of closed 5-dimensional manifolds under cobordism. Its class in the cobordism ring is the lowest-degree class not generated by projective spaces. It also represents the lowest-degree torsion in the oriented cobordism ring.

Comment: google says it has a metric with non-negative sectional curvature, (which is apparently quite rare)

Comment: Would "Geometric properties of the Wu manifold" be a better title for this question?

Comment: @j.c. I changed the title, but I still want rational homology spheres to be there, because it is a primary reason why I am interested in the Wu manifold.

Comment: Could you say more on what you mean by "geometric properties"?  And what mappings you wish to construct, i..e., from where to where? In any case I woud start by searching in mathscinet for SU(n)/SO(n) in the title field. In my mirror it yields 66 items many of which seem relevant.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I will describe it in another post because I want to provide some details. I will check MathSciNet for SU(n)/SO(n).

Answer (score 6):

Another feature of the Wu manifold which makes it an important example is that it is not spin${}^c$. In contrast, every closed orientable manifold of dimension at most four is spin${}^c$.

One geometric property of the Wu manifold is that it admits a metric of positive scalar curvature. Gromov and Lawson showed that a simply connected non-spin manifold of dimension at least five always admits a metric of positive scalar curvature.